# How to apply individual format/StringFormat to MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to apply individual formatting to each of the `Binding` element in a `MultiBinding` like so:

```
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringCascadingConverter}">
                <Binding Path="MyProperty" StringFormat="{}{0:F1}"></Binding>
                <Binding Path="MyProperty2" StringFormat="{}{0:F2}"></Binding>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
        <!--<Run Text="{Binding MyProperty, StringFormat={}{0:F1}}"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding MyProperty, StringFormat={}{0:F2}}"/>-->
    </TextBlock>
```

I cant use `Runs` as I am limited to use .Net 3.5, in which the `Run.Text` property is not dependency property.

In the sample above, the converter is picking up MyProperty and MyProperty2 directly, instead of the formatted value as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, but the answer is what you found as per the MSDN docs ([BindingBase.StringFormat Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx))

> If you set the Converter and StringFormat properties, the converter is
>   applied to the data value first, and then the StringFormat is applied.

---

With that said the work around is to modify or create a new multivalue converter which takes in the string followed by the format...do that for each string format pair.

If you are unable to modify the converter to do that, it is still possible. Simply create a new converter with the above motif, but after the conversion call the original converter and return its result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. According to MSDN, StringFormat applied to each Binding element will be ignored. I am adding a converter to the each binding element to do the formatting for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may probably just set the MultiBinding's `StringFormat` property:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:F1} {1:F2}">
            <Binding Path="MyProperty"/>
            <Binding Path="MyProperty2"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```